# Having issue with creating user registration with node

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, bcrypt

I am a beginner working with node and I am attempting to allow for user registration on a project. However, anytime I press the register button on my page I receive this error:

```
ReferenceError: bcrypt is not defined
    at model.<anonymous> (/Users/hossamalsheikh/Documents/Personal Projects/Web Apps/Gaming/models/User.js:29:5)
    at callMiddlewareFunction (/Users/hossamalsheikh/Documents/Personal Projects/Web Apps/Gaming/node_modules/kareem/index.js:482:23)
    at model.next (/Users/hossamalsheikh/Documents/Personal Projects/Web Apps/Gaming/node_modules/kareem/index.js:58:7)
    at _next (/Users/hossamalsheikh/Documents/Personal Projects/Web Apps/Gaming/node_modules/kareem/index.js:106:10)
    at /Users/hossamalsheikh/Documents/Personal Projects/Web Apps/Gaming/node_modules/kareem/index.js:507:38
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:79:11)
```

I don't understand what the issue could be. I gave both downloaded and required the bcryptjs module. Here is my code:

```
// Modules required to run the application
const express = require('express');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

// Creates 'mini app'
const router = express.Router();

// User model
const User = require('../models/User');

// Login Page
router.get('/login', function(req, res){
    res.render("./home/login");
});

// Registration Page
router.get('/register', function(req, res){
    res.render("./home/register");
});

// Registration
router.post('/register', function(req, res){
    const { name, email, password, password2 } = req.body;
    let errors = [];

    // Check requried fields
    if(!name || !email || !password || !password2){
        errors.push({ msg: 'Please fill in all feilds' });
    }

    //Check passwords match
    if(password !== password2){
        errors.push({ msg: "Passwords do not match" });
    }

    // Check password length
    if(password.length < 6){
        errors.push({ msg: "Password should be at least six characters long" });
    }

    // Checks for any errors and prevents registration/redirection
    if(errors.length > 0){
        res.render('./home/register', {
            errors,
            name,
            email,
            password,
            password2
        });
    }
    else{
        // Validation passed
        User.findOne({ email: email })
        .then(function(user){
            if(user){
                // User exists
                errors.push({ msg: "Email is already registered" });
                res.render('./home/register', {
                    errors,
                    name,
                    email,
                    password,
                    password2
                });
            } else {
                const newUser = new User({
                    name: name,
                    email: email,
                    password: password
                }); 

                // Hash Password
                bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err, salt){
                    bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, salt, function(err, hash){
                        if(err){
                            throw err;
                        }

                        // Sets the password to the hashed password
                        newUser.password = hash;

                        newUser.save().then(function(user){
                            res.send('/users/login');
                        }).catch(function(err){
                            console.log(err);
                        });
                    });
                });
            }
        });
    }
});

module.exports = router;
```

Thank you for any assistance.

Comment: Might be worth looking into the file `../models/User.js` line 29 as suggested by the error

Comment: My issue was there. Thanks a lot :)